# How effectively send messages to a group of email addresses using a central address?

Tags: php, email, laravel

I have to set up an email sending solution, and I haven't yet figured out the best way to do this, I hope you have some ideas. I would like to achieve the following:

- Have a central email address like mailinglist@mysite.com.
- Behind this list there is a database of email addresses. I would like  to be able to extend this list through an API. For example if a new user registers on my site, I want to add them to the list. Or if someone unsubscribes, I want to remove him from the list.
- On my website I will place a button, and if the user clicks it their email client opens with the central address prepopulated.
- If they send an email to this address, everyone will recieve it who is on the list.
- If someone replies also everybody will recieve it.
- (The application is written in PHP (Laravel framework) if that is important).

Do you know of any service where I can set up this kind of "mailing list", preferrably for free? (It would have a few hundred members, sending a somewhere around 30-100 emails a month.)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll need root access to your (linux) webserver - then you can hook [Sympa](http://www.sympa.org/) (read "list of features") into your MailTransportAgent (MTA) (postfix, exim) or whatever.

Comment: I am on shared hosting unfortunately and I don't have access

Comment: Can you trigger cron-jobs? There is a php extension called php-imap. You could write the php relay yourself using a database for your in/out email mappings (using PHPMailer for sending). On the other hand a vserver with 30gb space/1gb ram is only 40€/year last time I checked - you just have to set it up yourself.